# The volume in cubic meters of water in an aquarium...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The volume in cubic meters of water in an aquarium is given by the polynomial

$$V(x) = x^3 - 16x^2 + 79x - 120\;.$$

If the depth in feet (it really does say feet) can be represented by $x-3$, what are the possible dimensions of the rectangular aquarium in terms of $x$ if the aquarium holds $70$ cubic meters ($70 000$ litres).

I've gotten to the point of solving for the zeros to find $(x-3)(x-8)(x-5)$ but I don't know how to relate it to the $70$ cubic meters.

Comment: Is that really the depth in **feet**, not metres?

Comment: Do the side have to be integer number of meters?

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve the equation $x^3 - 16x^2 + 79x - 120=70$, that is

(*) $x^3 - 16x^2 + 79x - 190=0$.

But as you remarked $x^3 - 16x^2 + 79x - 120 = (x-3)(x-5)(x-8)$, so from $(x-8)(x-5)(x-3)=70=2.5.7$, you can actually *see* that $x=10$ is a zero of the equation (*)! Can you take it from here?